# VLOOKUP using dependent lists

Tags: excel, list, vlookup, excel-indirect

I'm really struggling to get this to work.
I have a data set of different types of steel, the size and weight. 
Example shown below:

```
A            B            C
Section    Designation   Weight(kg/m)
UB         127x76x13     13
UB         152x89x16     16
```

On a separate sheet I have a drop down list for "Section", then in the next column there is a drop down for "Designation" which is dependent on my choice of "Section". In my 3rd column I want to use a VLOOKUP to populate the "Weight" after I have chosen my "Designation" but all I can get is an N/A error.

My formula is as follows: `=(VLOOKUP,D12,Sheet1!A1:C1158,3,FALSE)`

Help me please!!

Comment: I'm not sure if this solves your question, but in your formula I see that VLOOKUP is referring to relative references instead of absolute ones: A1:C1158, while I would expect A$1:C$1158.

Answer (score 0):

I would use following formula:

`=INDEX(Sheet1!A:C,MATCH(D12,Sheet1!B:B;0),3)` You can add the lines to `A:C` if you like

Answer (score 0):

I suggest inserting a new ColumnA immediately to the left of `Section`, which I am taking as presently in A2 of Sheet1. Then in A1 and copied down to suit:

```
=B1&" | "&C1
```

For your separate sheet, to look up values from dropdowns in  D2 and E2:

```
=VLOOKUP(D2&" | "&E2,Sheet1!A:D,4,0)
```

There may be alternatives but it is not clear from your question whether, for example, a single `Designation` might apply to more than one `Section`. In the circumstances a unique key combining `Section` and `Designation` is safer.